# What are the other substitutes for an iron?

Tags: home, substitute-tool, clothing, laundry

Assuming I have a rumpled shirt and there's no electricity, how can I press the shirt instead of usual ironing?

Comment: Wear it for a while until the wrinkles go away. See also https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Man+iron.

Comment: What about a scenario when I'm late for a meeting and I'm the one to lead the meeting. Am I to wait until the wrinkles go away, before starting the meeting?

Comment: Dunno. Blast the heater in the car on the way there, lol. Or prepare ahead of time. If you have a meeting coming up, iron your shirt when you do have electricity.

Comment: Btw they make wrinkle release sprays. I know Tide does at least. Also if you have a car, buy yourself an inverter, an iron, and a small ironing board. Then you can iron clothes on the go.

Answer (score 4):

- Hanging in the bathroom while you take a hot shower.
- Place under a heavy object like a book (for a while, like overnight)

Comment: As long as there's still hot water left in the tank, since there's no electricity.

Answer (score 2):

Get it wet and hang it in the wind. A clothes pin prevents it from blowing off the hanger.

Placing between mattress and box spring works best with pants.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to follow the hack we used in our old days as described below:

[image: Get a steel plate as shown]

1. Place your rumpled shirt on an ironing table or on any flat surface unfolded (make it free from all folds as ready to get ironed)
2. Get a steel plate as shown
3. Pour not boiling water into it
4. Carefully plate it over your shirt and give it an ironing.
5. Please take care about your fingers while holding the plate.
6. If required you can place the plate on shirt and then move it over to various parts of shirt, thus reducing effect on fingers.(this depends upon material of your shirt)

Comment: You'll need a gas stove and possibly a match to light it, or enough hot water left in the tank, since there's no electricity.